# SQLiteException not an error at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)

Tags: android, sqlite, junit, sqlcipher-android

I am facing an issue while running the junit test cases in android studio.
The issue is very strange as when I run the test cases for the first time in the phone it works perfectly fine, but if the app is already installed and when I run the test cases I get following error:-

```
net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteException: not an error
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.<init>(SQLiteDatabase.java:1942)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:875)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:907)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:132)
at net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:99)
```

All the sqlcipher dependencies are correctly configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue.
When I saw in the logs, I found that the actual issue was

```
Unable to copy icudt46l.zip file
```

It was happening because i was not calling the `loadlibs` of `SQLiteCipher` inside the test suites.

So I added the following line in `setup()` method of my test class

```
SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(getContext(), getContext().getFilesDir());
```

Answer (score 0):

The database might not be properly closed after you run your app the first time. Try using Close method from SQLiteConnection class:

```
db.Close()
```